# Is a local Zookeeper cluster required to run Apache Storm in local cluster mode?

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have been trying to get a local copy of Storm working, following the guide in the [storm-starter](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) repo, and this [tutorial](http://www.haroldnguyen.com/blog/2015/01/setting-up-storm-and-running-your-first-topology/).

When trying to run a topology with `mvn compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology`, the output eventually continues looping & spamming:

```
28534 [Thread-9-SendThread(localhost:2000)] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
28534 [Thread-9-SendThread(localhost:2000)] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session 0x152f7728a6a0011 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
  at Sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
  at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[storm-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
  at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081) [storm-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

It seems it is trying to connect to a local Zookeeper cluster, but I have not seen the dependency or install requirement for Zookeeper in the Storm docs or in this other tutorial.

Do I need to install Zookeeper and is this just missing from the docs? Perhaps I'm mistaken and it is looking for something else at port 2000 on my localhost? If not, what is going wrong in my local setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run locally and use `LocalCluter` you do **not** need to install Zookeeper.

If you run locally in pseudo-distributed mode (ie, start up Nimubs and Supervisor locally) and use `StormSubmitter` you do need to install Zookeeper locally.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I posted another question regarding the errors I encounter when following the guide in the `storm-starter` repo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507922/unable-to-run-a-storm-starter-topology-from-the-storm-tutorial