# Unable to run a storm-starter topology from the Storm tutorial

Tags: java, apache-storm

When following the guide in the storm-starter [repo](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter), I'm unable to actually run any topology- like the `ExclamationTopology`.

`mvn clean install -DskipTests=true` ran successfully, executed from the top level Storm repo, as did `mvn package` at the `storm-examples` level.

When I try to run `storm jar target/storm-starter-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology`, I get the error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try  again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org/apache/storm/topology/IRichSpout
```

I'm running OS X, Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Maven version 3.3.9.

Does anyone have any ideas on why I'm getting this error and what I should change in my setup?

Full error output:

```
Running:     

  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0 -Dstorm.log.dir=/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/clojure-1.6.0.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/disruptor-2.10.4.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/hadoop-auth-2.4.0.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/storm-core-0.10.0.jar:target/storm-starter-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/conf:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/bin -Dstorm.jar=target/storm-starter-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/storm/topology/IRichSpout
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.topology.IRichSpout
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Edit:

After following the suggestions in the answers below of removing the `scope` line from the `pom.xml`, this error was gone, but replaced by:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar. [jar:file:/Users/zachary/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/storm-core-0.10.0.jar!/defaults.yaml, jar:file:/Users/zachary/storm/examples/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/defaults.yaml]
```

**Final Edit**:

For any future googler, I ended up not getting the `storm-starter`examples running via the commandline on a `LocalCluster`. I instead set up a new project with Maven, adding `storm-core` as a dependency, following [this] (https://github.com/mbonaci/mbo-storm/wiki/Storm-setup-in-Eclipse-with-Maven,-Git-and-GitHub) general guide. Then, in Eclipse, I was able to import the right packages from `storm` to do the examples, like `ExclamationTopology`. I rewrote that class using the same imports (changed to `import backtype.storm.Config`, etc). Then, running the file as is just works.

This [quick](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) Maven guide helps too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To be little bit more precise with regard to Nick's answer.

In `storm-starter/pom.xml` the dependency `storm-core` is specified with scope "provided":

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <!--
    Use "provided" scope to keep storm out of the jar-with-dependencies
    For IntelliJ dev, intellij will load properly.
  -->
  <scope>${provided.scope}</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you run locally using `LocalCluster` you need to include `storm-core` as dependency with default scope "compile", ie, just remove the `scope` tag, and run `mvn -DskipTests package` in `storm-starter` again.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Following this change, my original error did disappear and was replaced by `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar. `. I've modified by original post. I see you answered the same error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356292/found-multiple-defaults-yaml-resources). However, I am only using the bare `storm-starter` repo with no changes or custom bolts/spouts, so I'm not sure why I am running into this problem.

Comment: Well, `storm-started` was never designed for the way you want to use it ;) Thus, you need to adapt it to make it work for this. Btw: if you want to run the code in an IDE, it should be simpler than running it with maven over command line. You can basically just run the class containing `main` like any other regular Java program if you use `LocalCluster`.

Comment: Hm, I see. So I should loading `storm-starter` in Eclipse, or creating a generic new Storm project in Eclipse? Do you know what other changes I would have to make to `storm-starter` to get it to run in `LocalCluster` from the command line?

Comment: I would recommend to start a completely new (maven?) project. For `storm-starter` on command line, I would assume that the `default.yaml` issues should be the last problem to resolve to make it work (just edit pom.xml to exclude default.yaml for jar assembly -- even if I am wondering that this is a problem in the first place -- the issue should only be there for submitting to a real cluster but not for LocalCluster...)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I'll try that change to `default.yaml` to see if I can get this working at least. I mean, I don't have to do anything else to specify that I want a `LocalCluster`, right? Because I haven't said anywhere to pick local or to launch that specifically.

Comment: Have a look into the code ;) If you start without parameters, `ExclamationTopolgy` will use `LocalCluster`; otherwise, it will use `StormSubmitter`

Comment: Thanks again for the help! I've got it working as a new project with Maven and Eclipse. I've updated my original comment with more information.

Comment: Also, one has to  Tick - Include dependencies with "provided" scope in Edit configurations. (If using Intellij)

Answer (score 6):

NoClassDefFoundError regarding Storm, usually refers to errors coming from the `<scope>` tag in your pom.xml.

If you are trying to run the project on a cluster of machines where you have installed Storm, the `<scope>` should be "provided" (`<scope>provide</scope>`), else if you are trying to execute the topology locally, the scope must be set to "compile".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This change resolved this error but led to a different one.

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to run the topology locally, you should do it by opening the code and running it through an IDE, making sure that your code uses the **LocalCluster**. Looking at the code will also give you a better grasp of what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: My plan was just to follow the guide in the `storm-starter` repo to at least get it working, and then switch to Eclipse to actually look more into the code and play with changes. Do you know of a guide to run a Storm project using `LocalCluster` in an IDE?

Comment: The ExclamationTopology.java (which you said you are trying to run) has a main method. During the end of the main method there is an if statement checking for how many arguments were used to call this main method. If there are no arguments (which is true when you run it through Eclipse without parameters), then it gets submitted using the LocalCluster, else it tries to submit it to an actual cluster using the StormSubmitter.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue (Initially NoClassDefFoundError later multiple defaults.yaml)

For me following config change in intellij solved the problem.

Run ---> Edit configurations ---> Tick - Include dependencies with "provided" scope.

So basically when you are running in cluster mode, storm-core's scope should be "provided" in pom.xml. And above configuration will ensure that dependencies will be provided from cluster at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

the first time I tried to run storm-starter, I got blocked by the missing pom or some dependencies.

I read the document again. Then I found I should install the storm first from the root directory of project not the storm-starter directory.

scope provided should be fine.
IDE will try to find it from local repository